# Why it is giving me no such method exception?

Tags: java, reflection

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

class tr1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length < 1)
                throw(new Exception("baby its wrong"));
            Class s = Class.forName(args[0]);
            Constructor c = s.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, char.class, String.class, String.class);
            Object o = c.newInstance(Integer.parseInt(args[1]), args[2].charAt(0), args[3], args[4]);
            System.out.println("description of object " + o);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);  
        }
    }   
}

class A {

    public A(int a, char c, String... strings){
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(c);
        for (String q:strings) {
            System.out.println(q);
        }
    }   

}
```

Why this code is giving me `NoSuchMethod` exception? Any solution for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why this code is giving me nosuchmethod exception?

Because you don't have a constructor with the parameters you've requested:

```
(int, char, String, String)
```

You only have a constructor with these parameters:

```
(int, char, String[])
```

where the `String[]` is a varargs parameter.

The fact that there's a varargs parameter is basically a *compile-time* artifact. You can detect this at execution time using [`Constructor.isVarArgs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#isVarArgs%28%29) but that doesn't change the signature of the constructor.

> any solution for it?

Use the existing constructor instead :)

```
Constructor c = s.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, char.class, String[].class);
Object o = c.newInstance(Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
                         args[2].charAt(0),
                         new String[] { args[3], args[4] });
```

That creation of a `String[]` to pass to the constructor is basically what the compiler would do for you if you called

```
new A(Integer.parseInt(args[1]), args[2].charAt(0), args[3], args[4])
```

Comment: in new Instance do we actually need to pass it as an array??

Comment: @user3239652: Yes, because that's what the constructor accepts.

Comment: but then I have use varargs also,so that i do not have to pass it as an array

Comment: @user3239652: That's *only* relevant for the compiler. It doesn't affect reflection. You can detect it and make use of it in your own code, but you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: @user3239652 You can't use the varargs when you call it with reflection.

Answer (score 6):

Because an ellipsis is syntactic sugar for an array.

You should:

```
s.getDeclaredConstructor(int.class, char.class, String[].class);
```

(and as @JonSkeet mentions in his answer, you should also make your third argument an array in the `.newInstance()` invocation)